# Git merge reapplying ancestors?

Tags: git, git-merge

So I have one experimental branch and one master branch, both of which I'm constantly commiting to locally. For some reason, whenever I merge the master into the experimental, some commits that were previously already merged get reapplied. This isn't too bad normally; I just see a repeat commit in my log. However, sometimes it clashes with the work I'm doing in the experimental, and it just completely overwrites my work in the experimental.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is `git rebase` command that is a little bit complicated to understand in its full form. But you just have the simple case.

```
git checkout experimental
git rebase master
```